# How to use an ajax variable and a rails method in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm passing created_at back to my view with the `data.when` variable.

I now want to use the `time_ago_in_words` function on this data.

My failed attempt:

```
<script>
 $('.new_short_message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
 $( this ).before( '<p>' + "<%= time_ago_in_words(data.when) %>" + '</p>' );
 });
</script>
```

This works without the rails function (but I want to get time ago in words)

```
<script>
$('.new_short_message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
 $( this ).before( '<p>' + data.when + '</p>' );
});
</script>
```

Comment: try to format when with in the response send by the server `{when: time_ago_in_words(created_at)}`

Comment: check answers for this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor] it was for PHP but works for every server side language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Rails:**

Using `ajax` send `data.when` to receptive controller and get that desire 'words' in this `view`.

**In JavaScript**

Use this function to get `time_ago_in_word` in javascript. I got this code [here](https://gist.github.com/boxnos/5896114). So thanks to [boxnos](https://gist.github.com/boxnos).

```
var time_ago_in_words = function(from, to) {
 to = to ? to : Date.now();

var minutes = (to - from) / 60000;

var data = [
 [0 , 'less than a minute ago'],
 [1 , 'a minute ago'],
 [2 , function(m) {return m.toFixed() + ' minutes ago';}],
 [45 , 'about 1 hour ago'],
 [90 , function(m) {return 'about ' + (m / 60).toFixed() + ' hours ago';}],
 [1440 , '1 day ago'],
 [2880 , function(m) {return (m / 1440).toFixed() + ' days ago';}],
 [43200 , 'about 1 month ago'],
 [86400 , function(m) {return (m / 43200).toFixed() + ' months ago';}],
 [52960 , 'about 1 year ago'],
 [1051200, function(m) {return (m / 525960).toFixed() + ' years ago';}],
 [Number.MAX_VALUE]
];

function b_search(value, lower, pos, upper) {
 if (data[pos][0] <= value && value < data[pos + 1][0])
  return data[pos];
 else if (value < data[pos][0])
  return b_search(value, lower, Math.floor((lower + pos - 1) / 2), pos - 1);
 else
  return b_search(value, pos + 1, Math.floor((pos + 1 + upper) / 2), upper);
}

var res = b_search(minutes, 0, Math.floor((data.length - 1) / 2), data.length - 1)[1];
 return (res instanceof Function) ? res(minutes) : res;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use the `escape_javascript` method to escape strings. Like This:

```
<script>
 $('.new_short_message').bind('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status) {
 $( this ).before( '<p>' + "<%= escape_javascript(time_ago_in_words(data.when)) %>" + '</p>' );
 });
</script>
```

Otherwise this can cause format failures that cause javascript syntax errors.

Comment: I have tried this but get the error undefined local variable or method `data' for #<#<Class:0x007f97d68933a0>:0x007f97d6865310>